# HtmlAgilityPack и xNet

Tags: c#, xnet, htmlagilitypack

Всем добра! Использую xNet библиотеку и HtmlAgilityPack

Имеется код:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
HttpResponse resp = req.Post("здесь пост запрос");
HttpResponse resp1 = req.Post("переход на страницу после нужного пост запроса");
```

Вопрос в следующем: Как передать html код, который мы получили после запроса resp1, в HtmlAgilityPack для парсинга содержимого?

Либо `doc.LoadHtml()` и `doc.Load()` не работают, либо я использую их не верно! Помогите!

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен таким образом:

```
string k = resp1.ToString();
var htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(k);
```

Comment: Сделал проще, добавил переменную string и в нее стал выводить то, что получил с POST запроса. Далее просто обращаясь к этой переменной, беру HTML код из нее. Без текстбокса

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov поправил